# java.io.FileNotFoundException No such file or directory error but directory exists

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm getting the filenotfoundexception on my apps directory but my directory clearly exists.  I'm doing this on my local machine.  I'm doing a very simple post to a servlet.  Does anyone knw what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out this was due to my firewall (firestarter) blocking my servers ip address.  I allowed the exception and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

A few of thoughts (hopefully you haven't tried them :-):

Do you have read access to the directory?

Try putting in something like:

```
System.out.println("the directory = " + directory);
```

Assuming "directory" is the File variables that holds the directory.

Try putting in something like:

```
System.out.println("the directory exists = " + directory.exists());
```

and making sure it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have traversal authority to all intervening path segments, and appropriate authority to the final file?